# XElement deserialization

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem deserializing XElement.

Here is the xml code:

```
<phrase level="1">Where are <subject>you</subject> going?</phrase>
```

and this is the code for the class

```
[XmlRoot("phrase")]
public class Phrase
{
  [XmlAttribute("level")]
  public int Level { get; set; }
  [XmlElement("subject")]
  public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

It's possible to get the text value of phrase TAG ("Where are going?") in deserialization?

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution. It was easy, sorry!

My new class:

```
[XmlRoot("phrase")]
public class Phrase
{
  [XmlAttribute("level")]
  public int Level { get; set; }
  [XmlElement("subject")]
  public string Subject { get; set; }
  [XmlText]
  public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

...in Value field I can get XMLTAG text value!